# Print value from a list (The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous error)

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

Having a question. I am having a list of records and there is another list of records which i am comparing the first list. 
When i write line(inside row reading of first list:

```
    for index, row in output_merged_po.iterrows():
        stock = output_merged_stock[output_merged_stock['PN_STRIPPED']==row['PN_STRIPPED']][['Whs']]
        print stock
```

I get result

```
       Whs
 11763 VLN
```

Where 11763 is output_merged_stock id number and Whs is name of whs where PN_stripped matches.

But i fail to extract data for further processing. I just want to write simple if statetement where i can ask if `whs = VLN`. I wrote:

```
                    if stock[['Whs']] == 'VLN':
                         print stock
```

I got error: `The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I wrote:

```
                    if stock == 'VLN':
                        print stock
```

And i got again : `The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

How should i write if statement if i want to get result 'VLN'? As for example there are sometimes cases when stock output is sometimes 3 whs, where 2 of them are 'VLN' and third is 'XRS' and on that case i should see of 'if' output 2 times VLN without XRS

Comment: `  if stock[stock['Whs'] == 'VLN'].any:
                        print stock`     Does not work as it gives all values and i want to have particular ones only (as written above is there are 2 with 'vln' and one with 'XRS' so i should see only 'VLN'

Comment: You have to give more context! You mentioned the "sql" tag so I assume this is DB related. At the very least, mention which DB are you using and which Python library are you using to access it with.

Comment: Using SQL-Oracle, Python 2.7, library pandas.io.sql and pandas

Comment: You're trying to compare a df which is array like with a scalar hence the error I think you want this `if all(stock['Whs'] == 'VLN'):` or if you know there is only a single value: `if stock['Whs'].values[0] == 'VLN':`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to compare a df, which is unnecessary here by the way, with a scalar value which is incorrect as it becomes ambiguous for testing a scalar value against because you may have 1 or more matches.

I think you want:

```
if all(stock['Whs']] == 'VLN'):
```

or if you know there is only a single row then:

```
if stock['Whs'].values[0] == 'VLN':
```

example:

```
In [79]:
# create some dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(5), 'b':2})
df
Out[79]:
   a  b
0  0  2
1  1  2
2  2  2
3  3  2
4  4  2
```

try something like what you tried:

```
if df['a'] == 2:
    print("we have 2")
```

which raises:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

So we could take the hint from the error:

```
In [82]:

if any(df['a'] == 2):
    print("we have 2")
we have 2
```

We can use `all` with 'b' column:

```
In [83]:

if all(df['b'] == 2):
    print("all are 2")
all are 2
```

If you compared a series which had a single row value then you could do this:

```
In [84]:

if df.iloc[2]['a'] == 2:
    print("we have 2")
​
we have 2
```

but it becomes ambiguous with more than 1 row:

```
if df.iloc[1:3]['b'] == 2:
    print("we have 2")
```

again raises `ValueError` but the following would work:

```
In [87]:

if df.iloc[1:3]['b'].values[0] == 2:
    print("we have 2")
​
we have 2
```

Comment: EdChum, Thank you it works, but not in a manner that i would like to. For the FOR function i get these results then PN matches (comment above)

Answer (score 0):

EdChum,
Thank you it works, but not in a manner that i would like to. For the `FOR` function i get these results then PN matches:

```
          Whs
14883      _
15607     VKO
```

So if i put

```
if stock.iloc[0:3]['Whs'].values[0] == '_':
   print stock
```

I get result as above:

```
          Whs
14883      _
15607     VKO
```

Where i need only see 14883 _ line.

However, if i write second Whs name to look for (VKO) :

```
if stock.iloc[0:3]['Whs'].values[0] == 'VKO':
    print stock
```

I get empty line, no info is printed, while i want to see

```
          Whs
15607     WKO
```

To be printed. Same results i get with another yours function:

```
  if any(stock['Whs'] == '_'):
     print stock
```

How it is possible to solve that problem and see only a line which is needed to see?

Comment: Please edit this into your question not as an answer

Comment: As a new topic or how should i do this?

Comment: New topic: Print value from a list ( wrong output, need only 1 item from a list)